# NaN values when adding two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with different indexing that I want to sum the same column from the two dataframes. 
I tried the following but gives NaN values

```py
result['Anomaly'] = df['Anomaly'] + tmp['Anomaly']
```

```
df
    date           Anomaly
0 2018-12-06         0
1 2019-01-07         0
2 2019-02-06         1
3 2019-03-06         0
4 2019-04-06         0

tmp
    date           Anomaly
0 2018-12-06         0
1 2019-01-07         1
4 2019-04-06         0

result
    date           Anomaly
0 2018-12-06        0.0
1 2019-01-07        NaN
2 2019-02-06        1.0
3 2019-03-06        0.0
4 2019-04-06        0.0
```

What I want is actually:

```
result
    date           Anomaly
0 2018-12-06         0
1 2019-01-07         1
2 2019-02-06         1
3 2019-03-06         0
4 2019-04-06         0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is necessary align by `datetimes`, so first use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `DatetimeIndex` and then use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
df = df.set_index('date')
tmp = tmp.set_index('date')
result = df['Anomaly'].add(tmp['Anomaly'], fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Comment: correct however this just takes away other columns! In my question, I tried to keep it minimal so I omitted other columns. How can I keep them?

Comment: @Mohame Belahcen All columns are numeric? Then use `result = df.add(tmp, fill_value=0).reset_index()` after set index.

Comment: @Mohamed Belahcen So I suggest create new question with multiple columns and expected output. Please add also numeric and strings columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
pd.concat([df, tmp]).groupby('date', as_index=False)["Anomaly"].sum()

         date  Anomaly
0  2018-12-06        0
1  2019-01-07        1
2  2019-02-06        1
3  2019-03-06        0
4  2019-04-06        0
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot.  It's simple, efficient and preserves the integer dtype.

Comment: Nice answer. However I would like to preserve other columns in my df (that didn't put in the question to keep it minimal)

Answer (score 2):

**[`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):**

```
res = pd.DataFrame({'date':df.date,'Anomaly':tmp.Anomaly.combine_first(df.Anomaly)})
print(res)
```

---

```
         date  Anomaly
0  2018-12-06      0.0
1  2019-01-07      1.0
2  2019-02-06      1.0
3  2019-03-06      0.0
4  2019-04-06      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first set correct indices on your dataframes, and then add using the `date` indices:

```
tmp1 = tmp.set_index('date')
result = df.set_index('date')
result.loc[tmp1.index] += tmp1
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
```