# Sum two dataframes with different indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with different indexing that I want to sum the same column from the two dataframes. 
Based on a suggestion, I tried the following but removes disregards other columns like `cat`

```py
df = df.set_index('date')
tmp = tmp.set_index('date')
result = df['Anomaly'].add(tmp['Anomaly'], fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

```
df
    date       cat    Anomaly
0 2018-12-06    a      0
1 2019-01-07    b      0
2 2019-02-06    a      1
3 2019-03-06    a      0
4 2019-04-06    b      0

tmp
    date        cat   Anomaly
0 2018-12-06     a      0
1 2019-01-07     b      1
4 2019-04-06     b      0

result
    date           Anomaly
0 2018-12-06         0.0
1 2019-01-07         1.0 
2 2019-02-06         1.0
3 2019-03-06         0.0
4 2019-04-06         0.0
```

What I want actually is to sum based on index and keep the category column and `int` dtype of `Anomaly`:

```
result
    date          cat    Anomaly
0 2018-12-06       a         0
1 2019-01-07       b         1
2 2019-02-06       a         1
3 2019-03-06       a         0
4 2019-04-06       b         0
```

Comment: did you also try the other solutions?

Comment: How does `cat` get "summed"? What if the same date has different cat values in df and temp?

Comment: yes  I did. same issue can't adapt them to keep other columns. I could do it in a very inefficient way but preferred posting a new question with string columns

Comment: @cs95 I only summed on `Anomaly`. `cat` shouldn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `update`:

```
df.Anomaly.update(df.Anomaly+tmp.Anomaly)
```

Output:

```
           cat  Anomaly
date                   
2018-12-06   a        0
2019-01-07   b        1
2019-02-06   a        1
2019-03-06   a        0
2019-04-06   b        0
```

Answer (score 1):

### `concat` and `groupby`

```
pd.concat([df, temp]).groupby(['date','cat'], as_index=False).sum()  
                                                                     
         date cat  Anomaly
0  2018-12-06   a        0
1  2019-01-07   b        1
2  2019-02-06   a        1
3  2019-03-06   a        0
4  2019-04-06   b        0
```

---

### `set_index` + `add`

```
a = df.set_index(['date', 'cat'])
b = temp.set_index(['date', 'cat'])

a.add(b, fill_value=0).reset_index().astype({'Anomaly': int})
                                                                                                      
         date cat  Anomaly
0  2018-12-06   a        0
1  2019-01-07   b        1
2  2019-02-06   a        1
3  2019-03-06   a        0
4  2019-04-06   b        0
```

Comment: @MohamedBelahcen I'd imagine! Just wanted to throw out interesting alternatives no one else had posted yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56755319/3545273) that I had given on your previous question is still valid after minimal adjustments:

```
tmp1 = tmp.set_index('date')
result = df.set_index('date')
result.loc[tmp1.index, 'Anomaly'] += tmp1['Anomaly]
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

It gives:

```
         date cat  Anomaly
0  2018-12-06   a        0
1  2019-01-07   b        1
2  2019-02-06   a        1
3  2019-03-06   a        0
4  2019-04-06   b        0
```

keeping the `cat` column from df and keeping the type int64 for `Anomaly`.